# How to delete a symlink using Ant?

Tags: ant, symlink

I am trying to delete a symlink in ant script using the below line :

```
<symlink action="delete" link="/path/of/link/symlink"/>
```

But it is showing an error:

> Could not create tempfile in /directory/where/symlink/points

The `/directory/where/symlink/points` is supposed to be read-only.

Is there a way in which I could just delete the symlink and not mess up other things? It's a part of a big script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symlinks pointing to read-only resources may be deleted using the `<delete>` Ant task.

```
<target name="delete-symlink">
<delete file="/path/of/link/symlink" followsymlinks="false"
      removenotfollowedsymlinks="true" />
</target>
```

And this is from the `delete` Ant task documentation:

```
removeNotFollowedSymlinks  Whether symbolic links (not the files/directories 
                       they link to) should be removed if they haven't been 
                       followed because followSymlinks was false or the 
                       maximum number of symbolic links was too big. Since 
                       Ant 1.8.0
```

Hope it works.